# (Principiante) Problema con AddEventListener (addEventListener is not a function)

Tags: javascript

Soy un absoluto principiante y estoy tratando de manejar AddEventListener.
Sencillamente, el HTML consta de un div que debe cambiar de color al apretar el button. El error de consola es "addEventListener is not a function".
Observan algo en el código que pueda estar generando este problema tan básico?
Muchas gracias.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Listeners de Eventos</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling01.css">

</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="colordiv">EN ESTADO INICIAL</div>
  
    
    <button class="btnCambiaColor">EN CAMBIAR COLOR</button>

    <script src="js/js01.js"></script>
        
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*estado inicial*/

.colordiv
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:orange ;
    color:beige ;

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;

}

/*estado alternativo*/

.colorAlternativo
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:blue ;
    color:beige ;

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;

}
```

JS

```
let divEstado= document.getElementsByClassName("colordiv");

let btn1= document.getElementsByClassName("btnCambiaColor");
console.log(btn1);


btn1.addEventListener("click", CambiaColor);



function CambiaColor()
{
    divEstado.ClassListadd("colorAlternativo");
    console.log("cambió a color alternativo porque hizo click en el botón");

}
```

Según entiendo, addEvent... sería un método del objetobtn1 capturado. Al escuchar el click, simplemente debería llamar a la función CambiaColor y cambiar la clase. Entiendo que es algo muy básico. Y el error debe serlo también. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que document.getElementsByClassName devuelve un array con todos los elementos con esa clase, si es un solo elemento podrías acceder a el por su posición, ej: divEstado[0]. Si te fijas en "getElementsByClassName" Elements está en plural, lo que sugiere una lista.

Una forma de resolverlo es aplicando la posición como mencioné más arriba, otra podría ser reemplazar el document.getElementsByClassName por document.querySelector(".colordiv").
También si no se repiten en HTML podrías poner un Id al elemento y luego desde JavaScript capturarlo con document.getElementById("colordiv") o document.querySelector("#colordiv").
En caso de utilizar querySelector dentro de las comillas se utiliza "." para las clases y "#" para los id.

Lo mismo aplica para btn1.

Por otro lado el classList está mal escito.

Debe ser de la siguiente manera:
divEstado.classList.add("colorAlternativo")

Dejo link a documentación
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Luis! Muy clara tu observación. Saludos!

Comment: Me alegro mucho, quedo a las órdenes!